# Why this Union on two Dictionary doesnt work?

Tags: c#, linq

Code :

```
    Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>> first = new Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>();
    Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>> second = new Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>();
    second = second.Union(first);
```

seems that I missing a explicit cast?

Comment: You don't explain what your problem is.  Are you seeing an error?  Are you seeing an unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Union" returns an IEnumerable - not a dictionary.

If you want an IEnumerable - you need a new variable:

```
var newEnumerable = second.Union(first);
```

Or - to create a new dictionary:

```
second = second.Union(first).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

`second` is a `Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>` while the return type of your `Union` is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>>`. You will need to convert that back into a dictionary.

```
second = second.Union(first).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

As the comment points out, this may not work if you have duplicate keys. If instead you want to union the lists with matching keys in your two dictionaries then you can use a `Join`:

```
second = first.Join(second, kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Key, (pair1, pair2) => new { Name = pair1.Key, PuntoMappas = pair1.Value.Union(pair2.Value) })
  .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.PuntoMappas.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Union` sees your two dictionaries as `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>`s - it literally is only going *"have I already returned this KVP, return it if not, otherwise don't"*, not trying anything clever with merging lists from matching keys.

To achive what I believe you're looking for, you need something like

```
first.Concat(second)
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList());
```